# Renamed Term Set causing problem on SPD publishing workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, taxonomy

I have SP 2013 on-premise SP Designer publishing workflow based on 2010 template. I have an external email address in Termstore.

Thus on each phase of approval email goes to a different group of emails from Taxonomy. Since there is not enough string manipulation function on workflow template 2010 to trim, I created another calculated text field which separates the term set value `(PublishingService@myOrg.com|G9971585-56d9-8df0-8225-fwt08z40ew37)` with GUID and stores only term set label **i.e.** email address (PublishingService@myOrg.com).

Now the problem is the term set got renamed to `PublishingServiceLevel1@myOrg.com;` when the workflow triggers it fetches old value. I have verified that Taxonomy Update Scheduler Timer Job processed successfully.

Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Can't say I have any experience using terms/workflows in this capacity, but only thought would be verifying that the GUID is the same?  i.e. whomever did the rename didn't in fact create a new one and delete the old one.

One additional thought, since I somehow skipped you mentioning using calculated fields to do string separation - are those calculated fields correct?  I recall issues with calculated fields not updating without a line item edit (i.e. if you change a lookup value, the calculated column won't update without the item itself being updated; same was true for today function).

Comment: Thanks Jordan your suggestions helped me find out the way. I found the solution. Posting it to the answer sections. GUID was same, Timer Job didn't update the TaxonomyHiddenList

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy Update Scheduler Job did not update the values after renaming of term sets in Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList. Everything started working fine after updating the item in this list.